# Mathematics or statistics?

Tags: reference-request, statistics, education

Can you please tell me what is ((stochastic modelling and statistical analysis of spatio-temporal data)) related to?
I mean Mathematics or statistics? Is it good subject for student who interested in pure mathematics ?

Answer (score 4):

If [this newsletter](http://stat-computing.org/newsletter/issues/scgn-08-2.pdf) (American Statistical Association)  is any indication, then it seems that both stochastic modelling and statistical analysis of spatio-temporal data are highly relevant and of interest to statistics and statisticians.  Likewise [Statistics for Spatio-Temporal Data](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002348.html) was published as part of Wiley's *Series in Probability and Statistics*, if that tells you anything.

There are those interested in theoretical statistics who would argue they are doing pure math, and indeed, some are.

But the topics you mentioned are of particular interest within and relevant to applied math and stats.

If you're curious, perhaps you'd like to explore [The American Statistical Association's website](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.amstat.org/&ei=67OvULzbHurAyAHIm4GQCQ&usg=AFQjCNE6D0-8zvG-LIxOn2utSY6Kb9Vosw).

Comment: In German, there are the terms "angewandte Mathematik" and "abgewandte Mathematik". :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a good subject from applied mathematics and statistics, but it doesn't have much to do with pure mathematics. The terms "modelling", "statistical", "data" are the give aways.